# the sum of numbers at any row and at any column of this matrix is exactly 1.

Tags: graph-theory

All entries of an n × n matrix are non-negative. It is known that the sum of numbers at any row and at any column of this matrix is exactly 1. Prove that you can choose n positive entries such that all of them are from different rows and from different columns.

Comment: i tried to show an example by created a 2 x 2 matrix

Answer (score 1):

Do it by induction.

1. $n=1$. The only element is the solution.
2. Suppose that from any matrix with non-negative elements and strictly positive sums in rows and columns of the size $n=1\ldots k$ we can extract those $n$ entries. Consider such a matrix of size $k+1$. If there is an element which is equal to the sum of elements in its colun or its row, pick this element. If there are no such elements, pick any positive element. Remove form the matrix its column and its row. We are left with a matrix of size $k$ with strictly positive sum of elements in columns and rows.
3. Conclude.